# When staking for resources of cpu or bandwidth does it stack?

Tags: resources, stake

When you commit your eos for staking to get cpu and net. Do these resources stack on top of another?

As in if I earned 10 cpu and 10 net one day. I get 20 cpu and 20 bandwidth the next day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you `delegatebw` multiple times, the values stack.

You can verify this in [`contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidtth.cpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/905e7c85714aee4286fa180ce946f15ceb4ce73c/contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L261-L264):

```
totals_tbl.modify( tot_itr, from == receiver ? from : 0, [&]( auto& tot ) {
    tot.net_weight    += stake_net_delta;
    tot.cpu_weight    += stake_cpu_delta;
});
```

Comment: how do you delegate bw multiple times? I'm using the meet.one app so I'm not sure if I can delegate "multiple times"

Comment: haven't used their app, so i'm not sure i'm afraid. with cleos you'd run `cleos system delegatebw [OPTIONS] from receiver stake_net_quantity stake_cpu_quantity` multiple times